# npm update results in "rmdir"

Tags: node.js, npm

This has occured three times now.
I run `npm install npm -g` and it results in:

```
 npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
    npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "npm" "-g"
    npm ERR! node v4.4.7
    npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
    npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
    npm ERR! code EACCES
    npm ERR! errno -13
    npm ERR! syscall rmdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   syscall: 'rmdir',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
```

I then input `npm -v` and it returns `-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory`.

Im trying to upgrade to npm3.
Any ideas?

Comment: npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator. So do you try run this with sudo?

Comment: Yes I have tried it with sudo, and it still produces the same.